# Delete duplicates from list of lists as if on a necklace

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, permutation, canonicalization

Given a list of lists of integers, all of the same length, I want to regard two elements as equivalent if one is the rotated and/or reflected version of another (that is, if the two lists are the same if they are regarded as beads on a chain). So, for example, given

```
{{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, 
 {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2}, 
 {1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}, 
 {2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}}
```

I would like to return

```
{{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, 
 {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}}
```

or something representing one element from each equivalence class. I haven't written any code that actually does this; the only thing I can think of is something really ugly using a custom function for `Tally`.

Edit: Set equality is *not* what I need here, although the example I gave did not show it. For example, if two of the sublists were `{1,1,4,2,2}` and `{1,4,1,2,2}`, those are not equivalent as necklaces but `TestSetsEqual` will say that the two are equivalent.

And, in response to a question in a comment below, yes, `{1,2,3,4,5}` and `{2,1,5,4,3}` are equivalent --- if a list can be transformed into another by a sequence of `RotateLeft`s and `Reverse`s, the two are equivalent.

Finally, all of the sublists I'm considering are short, under ten integers, though there may be thousands of sublists in the input.

Comment: How long are your real lists? Is this considered to be equal: `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` and `Reverse[RotateLeft[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 2]]`?

Comment: Very interesting question, distracted me for most of the day +1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**A high-performance solution**

Since you are planning to work with thousands of necklaces, it may be much faster to introduce a canonical form.

The main point is to write a necklace canonization function, which for all equivalent necklaces should return exactly the same result (canonical form). You can then apply canonization function to all necklaces in your list and use standard `DeleteDuplicates` procedure afterwards.

For simplicity we can take `First@Sort@equivalentForms[necklace]` as a canonical form (here `equivalentForms` generates all necklaces equivalent to a given one). In this case the full solution can be written as:

```
equivalentForms[nl_] := Join[NestList[RotateLeft, nl, Length[nl] - 1], NestList[RotateLeft, Reverse[nl], Length[nl] - 1]];
canonicalForm[nl_] := First@Sort@equivalentForms[nl];
myDeleteDuplicateNecklaces[list_] := DeleteDuplicates[Map[canonicalForm,list]]
```

(thanks to @LLlAMnYP for suggesting a more idiomatic code for `equivalentForms`)

For your example we get:

```
smallList = {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2},
{1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2},
{1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2},
{2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}};

myDeleteDuplicateNecklaces[smallList]
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}}

**Benchmarks for large input:**

Let's take a list of 5000 necklaces:

```
largeList = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {5000, 10}];
```

and compare calculation times (in seconds)

**@kglr's answer**

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[f[largeList];]
```

> 158.356

**@halirutan's answer**

```
First@RepeatedTiming[deleteNecklaceDuplicates[largeList];]
```

> 1.941

**This answer:**

```
First@RepeatedTiming[myDeleteDuplicateNecklaces[largeList];]
```

> 0.077

As we can see from the benchmarks, for large lists this solution is 10 to 1000 times faster.

### Update: compilation and parallel evaluation optimizations

@LLlAMnYP and @halirutan showed that canonization procedure can be significantly optimized using  Mathematica's compilation and parallelization capabilities. They provided the following highly-optimized code, which calculates all canonical forms in parallel and gives further speedup:

```
canonicalFormC = Compile[{{list, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{l =
      NestList[RotateLeft, list, Length[list] - 1]~Join~
       NestList[RotateLeft, Reverse[list], Length[list] - 1]},
    Compile`GetElement[l, First[Ordering[l]]]
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
myDeleteDuplicateNecklacesC[list_] := DeleteDuplicates[canonicalFormC[list]]
```

**Benchmark of the compiled procedure:**

```
First@RepeatedTiming[myDeleteDuplicateNecklacesC[largeList];]
```

> 0.00576

Thus, compilation and parallelization optimizations give additional 10x speedup.

Comment: +1 for same thinking. I felt opposed to generating `2n` permutations, but I guess procedural code is simply slower in MMA than to simply generate everything.

Comment: The equivalent forms are more tersely expressed as `NestList[RotateLeft, list, Length[list]]~Join~
 NestList[RotateLeft, Reverse[list], Length[list]]`, the canonical form is then fully compilable. I'll add a benchmark.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP God d*** it. I thought for about 10 min if I can calculate a canonical form **without** creating all possibilities. It never even crossed my mind that doing exactly this would work reasonably fast, I fact extraordinarily fast. Has someone tried to combine my approach of doing everything in parallel with this here? Very good answer +1

Comment: @halirutan see my update, when compiled, +1 order of magnitude

Comment: @hal Also, as I learned, it's impossible to find the canonical form without O(n) time anyway, and my roundabout approach only complicates things to probably O(n logn)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Awesome. Let me put a preface to my answer about complexity and point to Shadowray's solution.

Answer (score 13):

### Preface

If one could create a function `f` that calculates a canonical form of a necklace that turns all equivalent necklaces `{t1, t2, ...}` into one unique form `t` the solution is simple: Take your input list, create the canonical form of each item and delete all duplicates. **If** the function `f` is fast, then this approach should be the way to go.

As shown in [Shadowray's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144722/187), the direct way of creating all possible allowed permutations and just take the *smallest* is incredibly fast, especially if you combine it with a parallel compilation as shown in my answer. Therefore, please go and check out his answer.

### Answer

If you want to calculate this on a list with *thousands* of necklaces of say length 10 you will need a fast approach (if you are not a very patient tea-drinker).

Let us first think how we can decide the equivalence of two lists `t1` and `t2` in an optimised way. I suggest the following sequence of 3 steps where each step is harder to calculate:

1. If the `Total` of the two lists is not equal, they are definitely not in the same equivalence class
2. If they are identical or identical to the `Reverse` of the other, they are in the same equivalence class
3. Assume we have `{1,2,3}` and `{3,1,2}`. What we do is we join one with itself `{1,2,3,1,2,3}` and now we go stepwise through this longer list and compare the current 3 elements. Since we already tested for exact equality, we start at position 2:

   - is {3,1,2} equal to {2,3,1}, no.
   - is {3,1,2} equal to {3,1,2}, yes!

If you do step 3. with both, `{1,2,3}` and the reversed `{3,2,1}` you catch all rotated/reflected equivalences. Let us compile this down so that we can parallelised compare one element with the whole list:

```
pickFunc = Compile[{{t1, _Integer, 1}, {t2, _Integer, 1}},
   Module[{t = {0}, t1Rev = {0}, len = Length[t2], res = True},
    If[Total[t1] != Total[t2], Return[True]];
    If[t1 === t2 || t1 === Reverse[t2], Return[False]];
    t = Join[t2, t2];
    t1Rev = Reverse[t1];
    Do[
     If[t1 === t[[i ;; i + len - 1]] || 
       t1Rev === t[[i ;; i + len - 1]],
      res = False;
      Break[]
      ], {i, 2, Length[t2]}
     ];
    res
    ], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
   ];
```

Taking your original `list` we can now test

```
pickFunc[list[[3]], list]
(* {True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True, True} *)
```

At all `False` positions we have an element that is equivalent to the test item. Why have I made the function return `False`? Because now I know which elements I have to take out for further processing.

The rest of the algorithm is as follows: We start with the initial list and its first element. We store the first element and pick out all that are not equivalent. This *cleaned* list is our new starting point and we iterate all over again. On our way, we collect all *first* items in `res` until our `list` to check is empty.

```
deleteNecklaceDuplicates[list_List] := Module[{l = list, res = {}},
  res = {};
  While[Length[l] > 0,
   res = {res, l[[1]]};
   l = Pick[l, pickFunc[l[[1]], l]]
   ];
  Partition[Flatten[res], Length[First[list]]]
  ]
```

Sidenote: I don't `Append` to `res` because it is slow. Instead, I build a nested result list with `res = {res, newitem}`. At the end I flatten out `res` and partition it again.

```
list = {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 
    2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 
    2}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
    2}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}};
deleteNecklaceDuplicates[list]
(* {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
  3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}} *)
```

**But here comes the cool part!** Using @kglr's implementation in `f`:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {500, 10}];

f[list] === deleteNecklaceDuplicates[list]
(* True *)
```

Let us time this:

```
AbsoluteTiming[f[list];]
(* {1.74933, Null} *)
```

and

```
AbsoluteTiming[deleteNecklaceDuplicates[list];]
(* {0.11883, Null} *)
```

But how fast are we on a list with *thousands*? Let's try:

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {5000, 10}];
AbsoluteTiming[deleteNecklaceDuplicates[list];]
(* {3.13899, Null} *)
```

I hope 3 seconds is fast enough.

Comment: The equivalence test is smart (+1), too bad it's slow.

Answer (score 11):

```
ClearAll[f]
f = DeleteDuplicates[#, MemberQ[Join @@ NestList[RotateLeft /@ # &, 
    {#, Reverse @ #}, Length@#], #2] &] &;

list = {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, 
   {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2},
   {1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}, 
   {2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}};

f@list
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, 
>        {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}}

Also:

```
<< Combinatorica`
ClearAll[dihedralL, f2]
dihedralL = ListNecklaces[Length@#, #, Dihedral] &;
f2 = DeleteDuplicates[#, {} =!= Intersection[dihedralL@#, dihedralL@#2] &] &;

f2 @ list == f @list
```

> True

**Update:** a version that avoids [Slots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Slot.html)  and [pure functions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Function.html) (`#`, `#2`, `&`):

```
ClearAll[f3, necklace, mytestfunction]

necklace[a_] := Join @@ NestList[RotateLeft /@ # &, {a, Reverse@a}, Length@a]

mytestfunction[a_, b_] := MemberQ[necklace[a], b]

f3[input_, testfunction_] := DeleteDuplicates[input, testfunction];

f3[list, mytestfunction]
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}}

Answer (score 10):

This problem is simple enough, that halirutan's brute force method is still $O(n)$ complexity for comparing two necklaces of length $n$ (which is optimal). But I would like to offer an intelligent approach, which although not being faster here (in fact it's probably not even $O(n)$) (turns out I was wrong), can be useful in many problems of this sort.

The solution is to define a canonical order for a necklace.

1. The first element shall be the minimal element.
2. If there are several minimal elements, we shall choose the one, whose neighbor (to the left or right) is smallest.
3. If this still doesn't resolve ambiguities, we will continue in the separately chosen for each of the minimal elements direction and check subsequent neighbors.
4. If all list elements have been considered and no conclusion is reached, prefer to take the sequence where the search went to the right (i.e. do not reverse the list).
5. And if even that doesn't resolve the issue, I'm almost confident it doesn't matter which of the remaining starting points is picked, the output list will be the same, but let's pick the minimal element with the smallest index as the start of the list in canonical form.

The code below does just that.

```
toCanonical[list_] := Module[{pos, l = Length@list},
  (* find positions of minimum element *)
  pos = MinimalBy[With[{p = Position[list, Min@list]},
     ArrayFlatten[{{1, p, p + 1}, {-1, p, p - 1}}]], 
    list[[Mod[#[[3]], l, 1] ]] &];
  pos = NestWhile[
     (pos[[;; , 3]] += pos[[;; , 1]]; 
       pos = MinimalBy[pos, 
         list[[ Mod[#[[3]], l, 1] ]] &]) &, pos, 
     Length[#] > 1 &, 1, l - 2] // First;
  If[pos[[1]] == 1, RotateLeft[list, pos[[2]] - 1], 
   RotateLeft[list, pos[[2]]] // Reverse]
  ]
```

The algorithm is realised by the repeated updating of `pos`; it is initially a column of 3-tuples.

The first element is the direction of search (`+1` or `-1`). The second element is the starting point of the search -- the index of one of the minimal elements of the list. The third element is the index (mod length list) of the next element to be considered (as described in steps 2 and 3).

`MinimalBy` with each iteration removes from `pos` the rows whose third elements point to an element of the list which is not the smallest.

The `NestWhile` runs a maximum of `Length[list] - 2` times, since the preceding code has already checked a minimal element and a neighbor. At the end, the first tuple surviving is selected (picking the first tuple fulfills steps 4 and 5, however I ran this on a large set of random numbers and it doesn't seem to matter, which tuple to apply to put the list into canonical form, the result is the same).

Finally the list is rotated left to put the element indexed by the second element of the tuple at the start of the list, if the search went to the right, or at the end of the list if the search went to the left, in which case the list is then reversed.

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[{{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2},
  {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2},
  {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}},
  toCanonical]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}}
> ```

```
lists = RandomInteger[3, {40, 4}];
GatherBy[lists, toCanonical] // Grid
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 0, 0}
> {1, 3, 2, 1}
> {1, 2, 0, 2}    {2, 0, 2, 1}
> {2, 0, 3, 1}    {3, 1, 2, 0}    {2, 1, 3, 0}    {0, 2, 1, 3}
> {2, 0, 1, 3}    {2, 0, 1, 3}    {1, 0, 2, 3}
> {2, 3, 2, 3}
> {2, 1, 1, 1}
> {2, 1, 3, 3}    {3, 3, 1, 2}
> {1, 3, 3, 0}    {0, 3, 3, 1}    {3, 3, 0, 1}    {3, 3, 1, 0}
> {0, 1, 0, 1}
> {3, 2, 2, 1}
> {0, 2, 2, 2}    {2, 0, 2, 2}
> {0, 2, 0, 1}    {0, 1, 0, 2}
> {3, 2, 2, 3}
> {3, 3, 2, 3}
> {3, 0, 1, 1}
> {3, 2, 1, 0}
> {1, 2, 1, 2}
> {2, 3, 2, 0}    {3, 2, 0, 2}
> {0, 0, 0, 2}
> {0, 3, 2, 2}
> {0, 0, 0, 3}
> {2, 1, 0, 0}
> {0, 2, 2, 0}
> {2, 2, 1, 2}
> {1, 1, 0, 1}
> {2, 1, 2, 3}
> ```

Speed turns out better than halirutan's solution, even after I compiled his `pickFunc` to C with `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"`!

```
list = RandomInteger[{1, 3}, {5000, 10}];
AbsoluteTiming[DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, toCanonical];]
```

> ```
> 2.81648
> ```

```
AbsoluteTiming[deleteNecklaceDuplicates[list];]
```

> ```
> 5.16653
> ```

**UPDATE**

*One more update: the 3rd argument of the `NestList` statements is replaced from `Length[a]` to `Length[a] - 1`. Besides the very fast parallelization of a compiled function, this is optimal, since finding the canonical from a list of all equivalent permutations is achievable by an O(n) radix sort.*

Since I've been foolish enough to try to implement my own canonical form finder instead of generating all valid permutations and letting MMA sort them (as in the answer by Shadowray), not to mention wasting several hours writing this and letting myself get ninja'd by him :-) I'll throw in a benchmark for his approach and an afterthought.

```
(* Shadowray's solution *)
myDeleteDuplicateNecklaces[list]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.202244 *)
```

However this transforms all elements to canonical order as well. If that's not desired then Shadowray's `canonicalForm` like so:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, canonicalForm]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.290911 *)
```

This can be made much faster by compiling the `canonicalForm:`

```
compCanonical = 
  Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}}, 
    Sort[NestList[RotateLeft, a, Length[a] - 1]~Join~
         NestList[RotateLeft, Reverse[a], Length[a] - 1]
    ] // First, 
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
```

Note how this leverages the special listability options of `Compile`'d functions: if I run this on a rank-2 array, it will map at level 1, while a top-level `Listable` function will map at level 2. So if conserving non-canonical forms is not necessary, one can do

```
DeleteDuplicates[compCanonical[list]]
(* ...; // AbsoluteTiming -> 0.0217732 *)
```

which is another order of magnitude faster. And if we want to keep the original forms, then

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[list, compCanonical]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.0797666 *)
```

Comment: Even though I didn't accept this answer, I learned quite a bit from it. Thanks for spending the time. +1.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution #1:**

The key idea is to transform a list of the base n digits to an integer.

The advantage of the solution is fast.

In:

```
ListUnion[xss_] := Module[{base, ZERO, yss},
  rotateLeftList[xs_] := 
   NestList[RotateLeft, xs, Length[xs]] // 
    Map[FromDigits[#, base] &];
  rotateList[xs_] := {xs, Reverse[xs]} // Map[rotateLeftList] // 
    Catenate;

  base = If[Max[xss] < 10, 11, Max[xss] + 2];
  ZERO = (base - 1);
  yss = xss /. 0 -> ZERO // Map[First@*Sort@*rotateList] // Union // 
    IntegerDigits[#, base] & ;
  yss /. ZERO -> 0]

RandomSeed[3];
(*original list *)
xss = {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 
   2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 
   2, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
   2}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}}
ListUnion[xss]

(*0 leading list *)
xss = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10, 6}]
ListUnion[xss]

(*Multiple digits number list *)
xss = RandomInteger[{10, 11}, {10, 6}]
ListUnion[xss]
```

Out:

[image]

**Solution #2**

The key idea is to transform a list of number/symbol to a string.

In:

```
  ListUnion[xss_] := Module[{base, ZERO, yss},
  rotateLeftList[xs_] := 
   NestList[RotateLeft, xs, Length[xs]] // Map[ToString];
  rotateList[xs_] := {xs, Reverse[xs]} // Map[rotateLeftList] // 
    Catenate;
  xss // Map[First@*Sort@*rotateList] // Union // ToExpression
  ]

RandomSeed[3];
(*original list *)
xss = {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, {1, 
   2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 1, 
   2, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 
   2}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}}
ListUnion[xss]

(* number list *)
xss = RandomInteger[{-1, 0}, {10, 6}]
ListUnion[xss]

(* symbol list *)
xss = RandomChoice[{a, b}, {10, 6}]
ListUnion[xss]
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: I considered this. If there are any leading zeroes or multidigit integers, those will be lost.

Comment: Thanks. I added a base, so I think it's fine now.

Comment: Could I know the `xss` mean what?Why are you presist to use it? :)

Comment: x is x. xs is a list of x, xss is a list of list of x. ;)

Comment: @ LLlAMnYP multiple digits natural numbers are handled as well.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer computes a canonical form for each necklace by constructing the entire equivalence class and choosing the minimal element under sorting. There is a lot of discussion in the comments about this; it turns out to be a faster option than anticipated.

However, for a list of $\ell$ necklaces with $n$ beads each, it requires computing $2n\times\ell$ total necklaces even though the final list may be as few as $\ell/(2n)$ necklaces long. If memory usage is of concern, this $2n$-fold blowup may be undesirable.

Here is a solution that is guaranteed never to compute any equivalence class more than once.

First, define your equivalence class in whatever way you like; there are several options in the other solutions. For myself, I will note that the full symmetry group can be constructed from $n-1$ copies of `RotateLeft` plus $1$ `Reverse`:

```
n = 6;

generators = Composition @@@ DeleteDuplicates @ 
  Subsets[ConstantArray[RotateLeft, n-1] ~Append~ Reverse];

equivClass[necklace_] := Through @ generators @ necklace
```

Now, rather than computing the entire equivalence class of every necklace on the list right off the bat, as in some of the other answers, let's just compute the equivalence class of the first necklace on the list, and delete any equivalent necklaces prior to moving to the next one.

```
removeEquivs[necklaces_] := Module[{tmpList = necklaces},
  Last@Last@Reap @ While[Length @ tmpList > 0, tmpList = 
    DeleteCases[tmpList, Alternatives @@ equivClass[Sow[First@ tmpList]]]]]

removeEquivs @ {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1}, 
  {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}, 
  {1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1}, 
  {2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1}, {2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1}}

(* {{1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, 
    {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Since each time we encounter a necklace, we remove all its equivalent necklaces before moving on, we will never have to compute an equivalence class twice. No real savings if our list doesn't have many equivalent necklaces to remove, but if there are a ton of "duplicates" then we might come out ahead on memory.